# What do i put for the value of a cookie set on a submit button's onlick to remeber its been clicked after a page reload?

Tags: javascript, button, cookies, submit, click

Confused about this...So I have a button that when clicked reveals a hidden div.  Im trying to set a cookie onlick so that the div will show even after the page reloads but Im having no luck...

What I dont understand is how to get a value for a clicked state...

For example:

`setCookie('CookieName', 'What goes here for the clicked button state value?', 'LENGTH OF COOKIE LIFE')`

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function SetCookie() {
if(arguments.length < 2) { return; }
var n = arguments[0];
var v = arguments[1];
var d = 0;
if(arguments.length > 2) { d = parseInt(arguments[2]); }
var exp = '';
if(d > 0) {
    var now = new Date();
    then = now.getTime() + (d * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    now.setTime(then);
    exp = '; expires=' + now.toGMTString();
    }
document.cookie = n + "=" + escape(String(v)) + '; path=/' + exp;
} // function SetCookie()

function ReadCookie(n) {
var cookiecontent = new String();
if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
    var cookiename = n+ '=';
    var cookiebegin = document.cookie.indexOf(cookiename);
    var cookieend = 0;
    if(cookiebegin > -1) {
        cookiebegin += cookiename.length;
        cookieend = document.cookie.indexOf(";",cookiebegin);
        if(cookieend < cookiebegin) { cookieend = document.cookie.length; }
        cookiecontent = document.cookie.substring(cookiebegin,cookieend);
        }
    }
return unescape(cookiecontent);
} // function ReadCookie()
// —>
</script>


<style type="text/css">
#sub3 {
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 200px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
width: 180px;
padding: 10px;
color: black;
border: #0000cc 2px dashed;
display: none;
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
}
</script>

</head>
<body >

<script language="JavaScript">
function clicked() {
    setVisibility(id, visibility);
    setCookie() // this calls your set cookie function
    return true;
}
</script>

<input id="input1" type=button value='Show Layer' onclick="clicked();">

<div id="sub3">Message Box</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `setVisibility(id, visibility)` accept 2 attributes, you need to specify values like `setVisibility('sub3', 'block')` if you want to show your block.

You nedd to pass arguments to your functions `SetCookie(name, value)` and `GetCookie(name)`.

Also you need to show your block in page load event if function `GetCookie(name)` returns value.

Comment: changing your first suggestion messed my code up, I dont know what to put under value for setcookie becuase i dont know what a clicked button's state value is.  "Also you need to show your block in page load event if function GetCookie(name) returns value."...dont know what your saying...but thanks anyways

Comment: you need to select name for your cookie, for exampe: 'divState', and your calls to SetCookie and GetCookie will look like: SetCookie('divState', [val]) and GetCookie('divState'), you need to replace [val] with value you want to save in cookie

On page load, for example in window.onload, you need to check value in cooke and call setVisibility('div3', 'block') if you want to show your block